# How do I use Firebase Database to display multiple routes/childs in Table View using Xcode/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my Firebase Database:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
class AdminSearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var jobList = [jobModel2]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tlb2: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! ViewController2TableViewCell
        let job: jobModel2
        job = jobList[indexPath.row]
        cell.ship.text = job.consignee
        cell.reference.text = job.reference
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return jobList.count
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
        Database.database().reference().child("jobs").observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount>0 {
                self.jobList.removeAll()
                for jobs in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                    let jobObject = jobs.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let jobConsignee = jobObject?["consignee"]
                    let jobReference = jobObject?["reference"]
                    let job = jobModel2( consignee: jobConsignee as! String?,
                                         reference: jobReference as! String?
                    )
                    self.jobList.append(job)
                }
                self.tlb2.reloadData()
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The problem I am facing is that their is nothing coming up in my TableView, I think its to do with the .childs, as I think I need to change it from just "jobs" to something but I can not figure it out.

I want to display the list of all the references from all of the UID's not just one.

CODE THAT DISPLAYS IN PRINT:

```
func readJobs() {


    let ref = Database.database().reference()

   let ref1 = ref.child("jobs").queryOrderedByKey()


        ref1.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            let allUsersAndJobs = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            for user in allUsersAndJobs {
                let uid = user.key
                print("user id: \(uid)")
                let thisUsersJobs = user.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                for job in thisUsersJobs {
                    let jobKey = job.key
                    let consignee = job.childSnapshot(forPath: "consignee").value as! String
                    print(" job #: \(jobKey)")
                    print("   consignee: \(consignee)")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as text, not links and images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

So that's not going to work - the firebase structure doesn't match what you're trying to read in.

Your structure is

```
jobs
   uid_0
      job_key_0
          ...
      job_key_1
          ...
   uid_1
      job_key_0
          ...
```

and you're reading the jobs node which contains the direct children but you're not reading the children of the children.

```
uid_0
uid_1
etc
```

So the Firebase structure is deeper than what you're reading so you need go read one level further down in code to get to the job child nodes.

Assumeing 5hs... and 7py... are user id's here the code to read each node, print the user uid and then their jobs

```
func readJobs() {
    let ref = self.ref.child("jobs")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allUsersAndJobs = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for user in allUsersAndJobs {
            let uid = user.key
            print("user id: \(uid)")
            let thisUsersJobs = user.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            for job in thisUsersJobs {
                let jobKey = job.key
                let consignee = job.childSnapshot(forPath: "consignee").value as! String
                print(" job #: \(jobKey)")
                print("   consignee: \(consignee)")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

and the output

```
user id: 5HS
 job #: job_0
   consignee: Anni
 job #: job_1
   consignee: Ralph
user id: 7py
 job #: job_0
   consignee: Larry
 job #: job_1
   consignee: Bill
```

Comment: No the  5HS..., 7py...  is users UID that was generated using firebase. Not a category, does this make a difference as it will not print anything?

Comment: @Wmwm19 Ah, ok that makes sense. No, it doesn't make a difference - it' still a parent node. Each one needs to be read in and then iterate over the child jobs node. I have update the code and adjusted the varaible names so it matches what you're doing. I duplicated your structure and ran that code and you can see the output is what you are asking for I believe.

Comment: Okay this is great, however now getting error of Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value . not quite sure why? Any ideas?

Comment: On this line:   let ref = self.ref.child("jobs")

Comment: Also, instead of printing this how to I put this in a table view? Is that possible?

Comment: @Wmwm19 You should take a minute to familiarize yourself with optionals in Swift and how to safely handle them. That error is likely due to a node not having a *jobs* child node or you've not defined self.ref. I define a class var *ref* within my classes to give me a consistent reference to Firebase.

Comment: That you, this works brilliantly now as figured it out. However again is it possible you could explain or point me in the right direction as to turn this into a tableView showing the results?

Comment: Hi, sorry Im not getting a new error for some reason on  "let ref = self.ref.child("jobs")"  of - Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

Comment: @Wmwm19 What did you define your *class var* of `ref` as? I have mine set up as a Firebase reference so whenever I want to call Firebase functions, I can use `self.ref`.